# angularjs capture html element and data that triggered an $exceptionHandler error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, error-handling

My app has a working `$exceptionHandler`, if an angularJS error occurs, it captures the error and emails the data back to me.  But its not capturing the HTML element that triggered the $scope function nor is it capturing the data that was passed to the function that caused the error to trigger.

To elaborate, I have multiple pages within my app that use that use the same controller which in turn are using the same functions.  As an example, the same validation `monitorLength` function is used on multiple pages where the user is inputting data, in some cases its on an `<input type='tel' ng-keydown="monitorLength($event,this.id,phoneLength,1)">` field, in other cases on a `<input type='number' ng-keydown="monitorLength($event,this.id,postalLength,2)">` field and in some cases the function is being called by another function.

But when the error/exception is thrown, all it tells me is something like the following making it almost impossible to determine which page/template/input field the function was used on or what the data was that caused the function to error:

```
Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'mLengths.length')
Stack: ionic://localhost/js/controllers.js:1291:47
```

In the error handling, how can I also get A) what HTML input/button/field that called the function AND B) get the data that was passed to the function that caused it to error?

Using the example mentioned, here is the monitorLength function:

```
  var permitChars = [8,35,36,46] ;  //allow delete and backspace
  var permitZip = [32,109,189] ;  //allow characters in zip code
  $scope.monitorLength = function($event,item,itemID,mLengths,deny) {
    //deny = 1 = phone
    //       2 = zip
    var keyCode = $event.keyCode || $event.charCode ;
    if (!permitChars.includes(keyCode)) {
      if (deny == 1 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(keyCode))) {
        $scope.errMsg = "Non-numeric characters are not permitted.  IE: + . , - etc" ;
        $scope.errColor = "red" ;
        $event.preventDefault() ;
        return ;
      } 
      
      if (deny == 2 && (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(keyCode)) || permitZip.includes(keyCode))) {
        $scope.errMsg = "Only numbers, space and dash/minus characters are permitted" ;
        $scope.errColor = "red" ;
        $event.preventDefault() ;
        return ;
      } 

      var len = $scope[item][itemID] ;
      if (deny == 1 && (/^0/.test(len) || /^1/.test(len))) {
        $scope.errMsg = "Country/Prefix code already selected, just enter main phone number" ;  
        $scope.errColor = "red" ;
        $event.preventDefault() ;
        return ;
      } 
      
      var maxLength = parseInt(mLengths[mLengths.length-1]) ;
      if (len && (len.toString().length > maxLength)) {
        $scope.errMsg = "Max length is " +maxLength+ " chars for this field"
        $scope.errColor = "red" ;
        $event.preventDefault() ;
        return ;
      }
    } else {
      $scope.errMsg = "" ;
    }
  }
```

And here is my error/exceptionHandler:

```
.config(function ($provide,apiServiceProvider) {
  $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', function($delegate) {
    return function (exception, cause) {
        // return emailApi(eType,cat,topic,subject,msg) ;
        var msg = "\nDateTime: " + new Date() ;
        msg = msg+ "\nAppVersion: " +appFullVer ;
        msg = msg + "\nException: " +exception.message ;
        msg = msg + "\n<br>Stack: " +exception.stack ;
        if (cause) {
          msg = msg + "\n<br>Cause: " +cause ;
        } else {
          msg = msg + "\n<br>Cause: none passed" ;
        }
        if (httpErrorID == 1) {
          msg = msg+ "\nHTTP Error: " +httpErrorMsg ;
          httpErrorID = 0 ;
        }
        if (errTesting == 0) {
          apiServiceProvider.$get().mail(5,"AppError","Bug","App Angular JS Error",msg) ;
        } else {
          console.log(msg) ;
        }
      }
  }) ;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking out loud.

Is `mLengths` ever `undefined`, etc?

Does setting a value for `mLengths` change anything?

```
$scope.mLengths = mLengths || [];
```

Also, refactoring like so

```
const index = mLengths.length - 1;
parseInt(mLengths[index])
```

could be useful in debugging.

In the same vein (removing the possibility of a null pointer). You could eliminate templates/views as the source by setting a `ng-placeholder` value for the elements. If the error still exists, it's likely from a function, not a template.

I have a feeling [`$event.target`](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts#handling-events) will tell you the source of the html. Though only if an exception is not raised.

I don't expect my code to work, only to express ideas.

Comment: I see your point. However, I’m curious if removing the possibility of a null pointer provides any insight into where the error is coming from. The optional assignment in my answer `$scope.mLengths = mLengths || [];` is intended to move you up the stack from the from the unhelpful error you are getting, thus providing the answer you are seeking. I have seen such refactoring work in the past. Though I do take your point.

Comment: ps - when life gives you lemons, make lemonade :)

Comment: its a moot point.  Your still trying to troubleshoot the code versus trying to answer the questions.  Change out this function for another one, the same fundamental problems still exists - if a function is called from 20 different locations, I need to know which location triggered the error.  Maybe its NOT the function versus the control data thats being sent to it\ - which means I need to analysis the control data.

Comment: Does the `$event` object (passed in to you `monitorLength` function) provide any useful information?

Comment: Also, what about the second argument  of monitor length? (`this.id`)